# CSS minify error occurs on VS bundled publish

Tags: css, deployment, bundle, publish, minify

We have a mvc project. After we have published the project with bundle, we noticed that some css bundles are not minified. You can see the errors from attachment.

We want to solve this issue without installing a plugin.

**What could be the possible reason causing this problem?**

Some errors;

```
run-time error CSS1039: Token not allowed after unary operator: `-c1-a1`
run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found `-`
```

here is css sample;

```
:root {
    --c1: rgba(74, 144, 226, 1); 
    --c1-a1: rgba(74, 144, 226, .1); 
    --c1-a4: rgba(74, 144, 226, .4); 
    --c2: rgba(255, 215, 60, 1); 
    --c2-a1: rgba(255, 215, 60, .1);
    --c2-a4: rgba(255, 215, 60, .4);
    --c3: rgba(108, 91, 172, 1); 
    --c3-a1: rgba(108, 91, 172, .1);
    --c3-a4: rgba(108, 91, 172, .4);
    --c4: rgba(108, 177, 87, 1); 
    --c4-a1: rgba(108, 177, 87, .1); 
    --c4-a4: rgba(108, 177, 87, .4);
    --c5: rgba(165, 20, 30, 1); 
    --c5-a1: rgba(165, 20, 30, .1); 
    --c5-a4: rgba(165, 20, 30, .4);
    --c6: rgba(255, 66, 66, 1);
    --c6-a1: rgba(255, 66, 66, .1);
    --c6-a4: rgba(255, 66, 66, .4);
    --c7: rgba(79, 84, 89, 1); 
    --c7-a1: rgba(79, 84, 89, .1);
    --c7-a4: rgba(79, 84, 89, .4);
}


.StatusLayout { position: relative !important; display: none; }
```

here is the usage;

```
.status-list-panel .status-span[data-color='c1'] { border: 2px solid var(--c1); color: var(--c1); }
```

[image]

Comment: provide some code of your unminified css. where you have `-c1-a1`

Comment: @AagamJain i added css sample

Comment: @KubilayBayraktar I doubt this is all the relevant CSS as there is no `-c1-a1` being used. However looking at it can it be that you use `var(-c1-a1)` instead of `var(--c1-a1)`? If that isn't the case you might want to take a look at your minifier to see if it supports CSS variables

Comment: i have added the usage, we are using visual studio default minifier. seems like it currently doesnt support css variables. But can we solve this issue in vs or we must install a plugin which supports it.

Comment: @KubilayBayraktar I think the easiest way of doing this is to use something like webpack. It will make your code much more maintainable also when sharing the code

Comment: lets take a look, thx